# celery shutdown worker after particular task

Tags: python, celery

I'm using celery (solo pool with concurrency=1) and I want to be able to shut down the worker after a particular task has run. A caveat is that I want to avoid any possibility of the worker picking up any further tasks after that one.

Here's my attempt in the outline:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
from celery.exceptions import WorkerShutdown
from celery.signals import task_postrun

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@task_postrun.connect(sender=add)
def shutdown(*args, **kwargs):
    raise WorkerShutdown()
```

However, when I run the worker

```
celery -A celeryapp  worker --concurrency=1 --pool=solo
```

and run the task

```
add.delay(1,4)
```

I get the following:

```
 -------------- celery@sam-APOLLO-2000 v4.0.2 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-116-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2018-03-18 14:08:37
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7f596896ce90
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[2018-03-18 14:08:39,892: WARNING/MainProcess] Restoring 1 unacknowledged message(s)
```

The task is re-queued and will be run again on another worker, leading to a loop.

This also happens when I move the `WorkerShutdown` exception within the task itself.

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print(x + y)
    raise WorkerShutdown()
```

Is there a way I can shut down the worker after a particular task, while avoiding this unfortunate side-effect?

Comment: Try using `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)` and see if it helps. Try with both approaches you already tried

Comment: If worker is child of a `celery` process then you should try with `os.getppid()`

Comment: Is the idea here that the worker would never restart after this single task runs?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: @samfrances, you have not provided feedback or comments on anything. Please update

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The recommended process for shutting down a worker is to send the `TERM` signal. This will cause a celery worker to shutdown after completing any currently running tasks. If you send a `QUIT` signal to the worker's main process, the worker will shutdown immediately.

The celery docs, however, usually discuss this in terms of managing celery from a command line or via systemd/initd, but celery additionally provides a remote worker control API via `celery.app.control`.
You can [revoke](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.revoke) a task to prevent workers from executing the task. This should prevent the loop you are experiencing. Further, control supports [shutdown](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.shutdown) of a worker in this manner as well.

So I imagine the following will get you the behavior you desire.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def shutdown(self):
    app.control.revoke(self.id) # prevent this task from being executed again
    app.control.shutdown() # send shutdown signal to all workers
```

Since it's not currently possible to ack the task from within the task, then continue executing said task, this method of using `revoke` circumvents this problem so that, even if the task is queued again, the new worker will simply ignore it.

Alternatively, the following would also prevent a redelivered task from being executed a second time...

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def some_task(self):
    if self.request.delivery_info['redelivered']:
        raise Ignore() # ignore if this task was redelivered
    print('This should only execute on first receipt of task')
```

Also worth noting [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.revoke) also has a `revoke` method that calls `self.app.control.revoke` for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you shutdown the worker, after the task has completed, it won't re-queue again.

```
@task_postrun.connect(sender=add)
def shutdown(*args, **kwargs):
    app.control.broadcast('shutdown')
```

This will gracefully shutdown the worker after tasks is completed.

```
[2018-04-01 18:44:14,627: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2018-04-01 18:44:14,656: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-04-01 18:44:15,719: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-04-01 18:44:15,742: INFO/MainProcess] celery@foo ready.
[2018-04-01 18:46:28,572: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery_worker_stop.add[ac8a65ff-5aad-41a6-a2d6-a659d021fb9b]
[2018-04-01 18:46:28,585: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task celery_worker_stop.add[ac8a65ff-5aad-41a6-a2d6-a659d021fb9b] succeeded in 0.005628278013318777s: 3   
[2018-04-01 18:46:28,665: WARNING/MainProcess] Got shutdown from remote
```

Note: broadcast will shutdown all workers. If you want to shutdonw a specific worker, start worker with a name

```
celery -A celeryapp  worker -n self_killing --concurrency=1 --pool=solo
```

Now you can shutdown this with destination parameter.

```
app.control.broadcast('shutdown', destination=['celery@self_killing'])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to shutdown a specific worker and don't know it's name in advance, you can get it from the task properties. Based on the answers above, you can use:

```
app.control.shutdown(destination=[self.request.hostname])
```

or

```
app.control.broadcast('shutdown', destination=[self.request.hostname])
```

**Note:**

- A worker should be started with a name (option `'-n'`);
- The task should be defined with `bind=True` parameter.